# Functors vs comparators

Tags: c++, c++11, comparator, functor

I know that a functor is a function object, an overloading of () operator in a structure definition.
Also the use of a functor in an algorithm seems pretty straight forward, just call this routine.

However I am not able to get a sense of comparators. Why are they used in the first place in a template argument.

Can someone please elaborate the difference between the two with a possible implementation of a template in STL like map

Edit :

I am looking for the answers to the following specifically

1. Why is that there was a need of comparator instead of a function object ( also comparators are more commonly observed in containers ? )
2. A possible implementation (non STL, i.e. in C++ code) of where a comparator is passed instead of a function object

Comment: You pass a type, rather than an object, so an entity can create a functor of that type and then it behaves as though you had used a functor

Comment: Ok, a bit of thinking makes me feel that its something with memory allocation, still if someone could provide an implementation it would be great

Comment: Functors are objects - they do occupy memory. There is really no difference except for either you providing an object itself or a type so the object can be created later on.

Comment: But passing as a type to template, implies I am not using memory ?

Comment: Not immediately. However, the thing you pass the type to *will* create a functor of that type. Effectively only the convention changes and you end up with pretty much the same.

Comment: It is better to use the term "function object" to avoid confusion. The word "functor" is taken by something completely different.

Comment: A "comparator" is a function or function object that compares, nothing more. Now, C++ has a trick up its sleeve. If you pass a type rather than an object to a function template, and let the templste create the needed object, the whole thing can be optimised more readily. For this to work, you need all objects of that type to behave identically. The technique is used for all kinds of function objects, not just comparators.

Comment: @Fureeish if you don't expose the comparator, and the compiler notices, it can elide the object and just call the correct code, under the "as-if" rule. This is being extended to members with `[[no_unique_address]]` in C++20

Comment: @n.m what is the definition of a functor regarding C++ then? An answer below states that it does not appear in the standard and I believe it's quite common to use either name. Can you provide references backing up your statement?

Comment: @Fureeish Functor is a term from a branch of mathematics called categiry theory, look it up. It turns out that this branch is pretty important in programming too.

Comment: Same genesis as the lambda. I really see no way of this naming to be harmful or confusing in any way.

Answer (score 10):

You are right about the definition of a *functor* - although the word doesn't exist in the language Standard itself, so there might be some slight variation in how people use it.

There are many function or class templates in the Standard Library that will take some sort of callable object - this might be a functor, or a pointer to a function (really just a function, not a class with `operator()`).

A *comparator* is an object of a type that meets the [*Compare* requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) - that is, a function or class object that can be called with two things and returns a `bool`, and in particular meets some mathematical requirements called *strict weak ordering*.

Essentially, this means a comparator is a functor that you can use to put some numbers in the right order. (Numbers, `std::string`s, `Customer`s, whatever else, as long as there is a sensible consistent way to put them in order).

So a trivial example of using a functor might be:

```
void print(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
// ...
std::for_each(std::begin(some_ints), std::end(some_ints), print);
```

but if you wanted to sort some `Customer`s by their customer id, you could do it like this:

```
struct Customer {
    std::string surname;
    std::string given_name;
    std::uint64_t customer_id;
};
bool compareById(Customer const& first, Customer const& second)
    // this function meets the Compare requirements
{
    return first.customer_id < second.customer_id;
}
// ...
std::sort(std::begin(customers), std::end(customers), compareById);
```

Let's say you later want to sort the customers by their names - surname first, then given name if the surnames are identical, you could provide a different function:

```
bool compareByName(Customer const& first, Customer const& second)
{
    // std::tie is an idiomatic way to correctly sort on multiple values
    return std::tie(first.surname, first.given_name)
                < std::tie(second.surname, second.given_name);
}
std::sort(std::begin(customers), std::end(customers), compareByName);
```

---

I'm struggling to invent an example where you would need your comparator to be a class, but let's suppose you wanted to print out all the comparisons it does to a log file; then that file would need to be state stored by the object:

```
struct LoggingCustomerComparator {
    std::ostream& logFile;
    LoggingCustomerComparator(std::ostream& logFile) : logFile(logFile) {}
    bool operator()(Customer const& first, Customer const& second)
    {
        // assume we have an operator<< for Customer
        logFile << "Comparing: " << first << " and " << second << '\n';
        return first.customer_id < second.customer_id;
    }
};
// ...
using OrderId = std::uint64_t;
using LCC = LoggingCustomerComparator;
std::map<Customer, OrderId, LCC> latestCustomerOrder(LCC(std::clog));
//                          ^^^ type                 ^^^ construct object with the log file we want
```

---

The above illustrates how to use function templates that *take* a functor or comparator, but what if you want to *write* such a function template? Let's implement [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort), in the style of a Standard Library algorithm:

```
template <typename RandIt, typename Comp>
void bogosort(RandIt first, RandIt last, Comp comp)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    while ( !std::is_sorted(first, last, comp) ) {
        std::shuffle(first, last, g);
    }
}
```

To see how `is_sorted` might be implemented [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until#Possible_implementation).

Comment: Good answer :) 
To expand upon this further you could have another function `bool compareBySurname(Customer const& first, Customer const& second) {  return first.surname < second.surname; }`

Comment: Your answer elaborates about functors, but can you please provide an example of a type where template requires a comparator type (like a possible implementation of an STL template in C++ code)

Answer (score 0):

In the comment section, a user has pointed the correct answer, and looking back I am just expanding on it

Basically comparators are types instead of an object, so passing types makes more sense to template classes, since its metaprogramming, that is the compiler is writing its own code, so it makes more sense that a class creates internal objects on its own rather than relying on the user to provide one.